# What's best option if all I want is flexbox classes from angular-material?

Tags: css, angular-material

I'm a really big fan of using angular material. However, a new project I'm working on doesn't use angular and I want some of the layout goodness.

For example:

```
<div flex="50"></div>
```

or

```
<div layout="column"></div>
```

I like being able to use these attributes to specify layout. Is there a smaller framework that I could use that provides these attribute selectors besides angular-material.css?

Comment: Looks like you can build the components individual. So for example build all of them individual and then just use the core module, which should include what you are looking for. [**Building Individual Components**](https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/docs/guides/BUILD.md#comp_builds)

Comment: Can't you just use CSS? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I'd prefer to use something that handles vendor specifics and is maintained and used by many.

Answer (score 0):

If you us angular but not angular-materil, a small option to enable flexbox is angular-flex

https://github.com/mogobruno/angular-flex